# Mask is making my header content dark too instead of just the background image

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

The mask i am applying should only make my background image darker but its making my h1 and button darker too

```
        <!-- Header - set the background image for the header in the line below-->
      <header class="bg-image d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
      style="background-image: url('img/orange.jpg');
      background-size: cover;
      height: 75vh">
      
      <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)"></div>

          <div class="text-center my-5">
           
            <h1 class="text-white p-5">100% blended fruit juice concentrate<span style = "display: block;">specifically designed for childcare centers</span> </h1>

            <a href="./ordernow.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Order Now</a>
            
         
          </div>
      </header>
```

I expected it to only make the background image darker

Comment: Can you provide the styles applied on `header` and `div.mask`

Comment: No styles were applied to them

Answer (score 0):

Modified the styles to adjust the layout of the `div`s

```css
header {
  position: relative;
}

.mask {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.text-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<header class="bg-image d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="background-image: url('img/orange.jpg');
      background-size: cover;
      height: 75vh">

  <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)"></div>

  <div class="text-center my-5">

    <h1 class="text-white p-5">
      100% blended fruit juice concentrate<span style="display: block;">specifically designed for childcare centers</span>
    </h1>
    <a href="./ordernow.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Order Now</a>

  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I tried it didnt work

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what the issue is

Comment: @JohnJohnson Updated my answer. Please check